# How to deploy and host .NET Core self-hosted console apps in Azure?

Tags: azure, asp.net-core

App 1: I have a React app (based on create-react-app) which I've added as a Web App in Azure - that was pretty straight-forward to setup. This is using the JS SignalR client to communicate with the server, mentioned next.

App 2: This app is the ASP.NET Core [SignalR](https://github.com/aspnet/SignalR) Server application created with dotnet new console. This app exposes a SignalR endpoint and is "self hosted".

App 3: A 2nd ASP.NET Core console app is setup as a SignalR client. This is responsible to fetching some data, and sends those data to the SignalR server. This takes the SignalR endpoint (url) as a commandline argument.

Running all this locally is pretty straightforward:

App 1: npm start / serve -s build

App 2: dotnet run -commandline args (runs on localhost taking a hubpath and port from the args supplied. The port is so that multiple instances SignalR servers can run on localhost - not sure if this is the way to do it in Azure or if they're differentiated with separate urls and hosted seperately there)

App 3: dotnet run "http://localhost:5000/somenotificationhubname"

I've added a bat file in each of the console apps, so I can open multiple instances of those, with different args.

So locally it runs as easily as clicking 3 bat files.

But I'm kinda lost on how to host all this in Azure. The web app seemed pretty straightforward. I just created a web app in Azure, connected to it through an FTP client and copied over the contents of the build folder from the React app.

But what to do with the ASP.NET Core console applications so that the SignalR console app will be hosted in Azure and has its endpoint exposed for the other 2 apps to consume?

I tried adding both both App 2 and 3 as webjobs under App 1, but that didn't seem to work.

I've also heard that SignalR should not be running on IIS, so would it make sense to make it self-contained (exe) and run it inside a docker container? Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Regarding webjobs you say 'that didn't seem to work'. What didn't? Any error messages or other problems you ran into?

Comment: Well they did seem to run, if I chose continous - but since the processes should run until manually terminated, logically I would assume "triggered" was more correct, and then starting them manually. The big problem however was that I would not reach the signalr endpoint from the web app's url + the port which was explicitly added to the signalr webjob from the commandline arguments inside its batch file. The batch file simply had a dotnet run [path] [port] and the log shows that it did start up - but exits early unless "continous" is chosen. Even then, it doesn't respond to the url

Comment: What version of SignalR? There aren't any supported released yet.

Comment: https://github.com/aspnet/SignalR - I'm using one of the dev releases that support groups and others. But latest release is https://github.com/aspnet/SignalR/releases/tag/1.0.0-alpha2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I will suggest to change your app to use AppSettings file for configuration values instead of the commandline args.

> 1. You can easily change the value of appsettings without redeploying or changing anything.
> 2. You can have multiple appsettings file based on environments.
> 3. Allows you to easily duplicate the app with same code but different appsettings for your multiple signalr server.

This will make it easier to deploy using the standard publishing wizard in [Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/publish-to-azure-webapp-using-vs) or via command line.

Comment: I agree with using appsettings over command line args. But how would you host it?

Comment: Just go though the link posted earlier, you simply publish the webapp to azure using either powershell cli or with visual studio wizard.

Answer (score 0):

You could try the publish Profile in Azure App Service with the help of Visual Studio,

[Reference 1](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/uk_faculty_connection/2015/07/20/using-visual-studio-2015-and-deploying-your-first-web-app-to-your-free-azure-subscription)

[Reference 2](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/how-to-deploy-web-app-to-azure-using-visual-studio/)

Once you successfully publish your webApp. You can double check the deployment using kudu service (or) App service editor

- [Advanced Tool-KUDU](http://www.jamessturtevant.com/posts/How-to-add-edit-and-remove-files-in-your-azure-webapp-using-the-kudu-service-dashboard)
- [AppService editor](https://developingdane.com/azure-app-service-editor/)